# How can I solve the conditional OR problem

Tags: javascript

I want the leap year and the following year to be "22" and the rest "23".

var hdag = ((Date.isLeapYear(year) || (Date.isLeapYear(year)+1)) ? "23" : "22") + "/9";

Comment: Do you mean `Date.isLeapYear(year-1)` to see if the *previous year* was a leap year? Also, if only those two should be `"22"`, then you need to swap `"23" : "22"` to be `"22" : "23"`

Answer (score 0):

I am not exactly sure what you wanted to do by this because the question is written in odd way, but please try this:

```
let thisYear = (Date.isLeapYear(year)) ? "22" : "23") + "/9",
    nextYear = thisYear


console.log(`This year is ${thisYear}, and next year is ${nextYear}`)
```